# Inno Setup is skipping my exe because it has the same version

Tags: installation, inno-setup

During the installation of a newer version of my program Inno Setup checks the version of my program. Then it detects that it has the same version and it skips the exe file...

How can I prevent that Inno Setup is checking the version and simply replaces the file?

See below a part of the LOG file

```
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   -- File entry --
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\program\program.exe
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Time stamp of our file: 2016-09-03 15:47:10.000
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Dest file exists.
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Time stamp of existing file: 2016-08-05 12:05:50.000
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Version of our file: 2.6.0.0
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Version of existing file: 2.6.0.0
2016-09-03 16:35:17.907   Same version. Skipping.
```

Answer (score 2):

As @SteinÅsmul commented, using the same version for actually different version of binary files is not good practice.

---

Anyway, if you need to workaround that bad practice, use the [`ignoreversion` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=ignoreversion):

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```